# check the field has value and print the value

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I want to check the specific field has the value and then print value.I want to check the field 'field_perspective_video' which is in video embed field and print the frame.If the field has no value then need to print the image field

```
<div class="imageAlign">
    <div class="perspectivecontetImage">
        <?php if(!empty($fields['field_perspective_video']))
        {
        ?>
        <iframe src="<?php echo strip_tags($fields['field_perspective_video']->content);?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <?php
        }
        else{

        echo 'hello'.strip_tags($fields['field_perspective_image']->content);
        }?>

    </div>
</div>
```

now It's printing empty frame not null value

Comment: Can you print and post sample array `$fields`? It seems your array `$fields['field_perspective_video']` is set but its content is blank `$fields['field_perspective_video']->content`.

Comment: yes content is blank.I tried if condition with content but still not printing my else statement

Comment: can you post your array?